# Get SMS Delivery Report with in service

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to send sms when my mobile get rebooted.My code is working in activity,I can get the delivery report in activity.But I put the same code in Broadcastreceiver, It is not working.

```
                   try 
                     {

                        String SENT      = "SMS_SENT";


                    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

                    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
                        {
                            int resultCode = getResultCode();
                            switch (resultCode) 
                            {


                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:                 
                                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                           break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                           break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                           break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                           break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                           break;
                            }
                        }
                    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                               SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                               smsMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null,"Send sms", sentPI, null);

                                }
                     catch (Exception e) 
                     {
                        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage()+"!\n"+"Failed to send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
```

How to use this code with in broadcastreceiver or in service?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot register a `BroadcastReceiver` in a `BroadcastReceiver` because the `BroadcastReceiver` does not live very long (only for the duration of the call to `onReceive()`. So what you need to do is to start a `Service` from your `BroadcastReceiver` and have it send the SMS. The code you have should work from a `Service`.

Comment: how can i handle the exception in service when sending sms?

Comment: Example,when rebooting,i'm having 0 balance,At that time sms not sent, The service wait until the sms sent.For that how can i handle this

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. In `Service` you call `sendTextMessage()`. When the message is successfully sent (or unsuccessfully failed) you will get a delivery report. The delivery report is broadcast, so it will show up in your `onReceive()` method. What else do you want to know? What's the problem? What isn't working? What don't you understand?

Comment: I want my service run background until the sms sent.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Your service is running in the background. When the SMS is sent the `onReceive()` method will be called on the registered receiver. So what's the problem?

Comment: First time i reboot my device without sim card.it show no service and it terminated.But i want my service run until, wait for inserting sim card and send sms(watching in background).My service will terminate when it send sms to desc. address.

Comment: How to receive back sent and delivery pendingintents in the service?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use **SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:** since its deprecated instead use  android.telephony.SmsManager [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE)

Once reboot call the **Broadcast Reciever**:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
    context.startService(service);
  }
}
```

**Your Service:**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class YourService extends Service {


 @Override
 public void onCreate() {

 }

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  super.onStart(intent, startId);

  //
  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(number to send , null, text, null, null);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

 }

}
```

Make Sure u add the required permission,receiver and service in Manifest File

Comment: how can i handle the exception in service sending sms?

Comment: Exception ?? u can use try/catch block in oncreate method.

Comment: how come i know the sms sent or not?

Comment: Example,when rebooting,i'm having 0 balance,At that time sms not sent, The service wait until the sms sent.For that how can i handle this.

Comment: u need to create PendingIntent and pass it sendTextMessage(String, String, String, PendingIntent, PendingIntent)
(Link)[http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/sending-sms-directly-from-an-application-using-smsmanager-in-android/]