# Get SMS Delivery Report with ADB Commands

Tags: android, shell, sms, adb

Is it possible to get sms delivery report on android using ADB commands ? If yes,  how ?

Regards

Comment: Please do your research before you post a question and post a question if you're stuck somewhere. Guide to ask questions here:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have ,...  i did not get much on the internet. if you have a link,  pleas share

Comment: This might be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589642/sms-delivery-report-in-android)

Comment: Or these - [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308062/get-sms-delivery-report-with-in-service) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875354/android-sms-message-delivery-report-intent)